# How do I tell which radio button was selected in file HTML-Twig

Tags: php, html, symfony

I have 4 radio buttons in my code HTML:

```
<input id="spa-price" name="price" class="w3-radio" value="Spare {{ price.getSparePrice }}" type="radio">
<input id="spa-price" name="price" class="w3-radio" value="Repair {{ price.getRepairPrice }}" type="radio">
<input id="spa-price" name="price" class="w3-radio" value="Test {{ price.getTestPrice }}" type="radio">
<input id="spa-price" name="price" class="w3-radio" value="Std-Exchange {{ price.getExchangePrice }}" type="radio">
```

On post, I want to output a hidden field with the value of the selected radio button, eg:

```
<input type="hidden" name="lt" value="{{ price.getLt }}">
```

The code I have at the moment:

```
{% if $_POST['price'] == 'Spare' %}
<input type="hidden" name="lt" value="{{ price.getLt }}">

{% elseif $_POST['price'] == 'Repair' %} 
<input type="hidden" name="lt" value="{{ 10 }}">

{% elseif $_POST['price'] == 'Test' %} 
<input type="hidden" name="lt" value="{{ 10 }}">

{% else $_POST['price'] == 'Exchange' %} 
<input type="hidden" name="lt" value="{{ price.getLt }}">
```

Currently, this does not work.

What is my error ? Thank you.

Comment: I am afraid your question is somewhat unclear to me. Mainly the part of the error. Did you get one? if so please show it as well. Or do you want to know how to retrieve this error?

Comment: I'm sorry, my question is how to do a test for these each radiobox in a file html.twig.

Comment: I changed it like this but it dosen't work:  {% if price.Spare == 1 %}
        <input type="hidden" name="lt" value="{{ price.getLt }}">

        {% elseif price.Repair == 1 %} 
        <input type="hidden" name="lt" value="10">
        
        {% elseif price.Test == 1 %} 
        <input type="hidden" name="lt" value="10">

        {% else %} 
        <input type="hidden" name="lt" value="{{ price.getLt }}">  
        {% endif %}

Comment: I think you are mixing up logic that happens when the page is rendered (i.e., your twig template) with testing for things that happen on the client side after rendering (i.e., which radio button was clicked)? Checking the status of a radio button will not happen in the twig template, but will instead happen in javascript as suggested by KevinTheGreat below.

Answer (score 2):

First, you have given every checkbox you made the same `id` that is bad practice. In HTML every `id` should have an unique name. I suggest you do the same for names. But for now that is optional

So change your `id's` to this:

```
<input id="spare-price" name="price" class="w3-radio" value="Spare {{ price.getSparePrice }}" type="radio">
<input id="repair-price" name="price" class="w3-radio" value="Repair {{ price.getRepairPrice }}" type="radio">
<input id="test-price" name="price" class="w3-radio" value="Test {{ price.getTestPrice }}" type="radio">
<input id="exchange-price" name="price" class="w3-radio" value="Std-Exchange {{ price.getExchangePrice }}" type="radio">
```

You can use Javascript to check if a box is checked

```
{% block javascripts%}
  <script>
        function validate(){
          var spare= document.getElementById('spare-price');
          if (spare.checked){
            alert("checked") ;
          }else{
            alert("You didn't check spare-price! Let me check it for you.")
          }
        }
     </script>
    {% endblock %}
```

Comment: I'm sorry for this disturb. I added a script in the file HTML.twig:     <script>
        function validate(){
            var spare= document.getElementById('spa-price');
            var repair= document.getElementById('tes-price');
            var test= document.getElementById('rep-price');
            if (spare.checked){
                 <input type="hidden" name="lt" value="{{ price.getLt }}">         elseif (repair.checked)  <input type="hidden" name="lt" value="10">      
                      elseif (test.checked)
                 <input type="hidden" name="lt" value="10">

Comment: But I can't know how to change the value of the input. I'm doing it in the function but he dosen't change. I should add it in the html but I don't know how exactly.

Comment: I tried by this solution:  {% if document.getElementById('tes-price').checked = true %}{
                 <input type="hidden" name="lt" value="10"> 
            }
        {% elseif document.getElementById('rep-price').checked = true %} {
            <input type="hidden" name="lt" value="10"> 
            }            
        {% else document.getElementById('spa-price').checked = true %} {
             <input type="hidden" name="lt" value="{{ price.getLt }}">
        }
        {%endif%}

Comment: but it display an error:              Twig_Error_Syntax in TokenStream.php
Unexpected token "operator" of value "=" ("end of statement block" expected) in "/cart/formAddToCart.html.twig"

Comment: I wrote it in the HTML like this : {% if document.getElementById('tes-price').checked = true %}{ <input type="hidden" name="lt" value="10"> } {% elseif document.getElementById('rep-price').checked = true %} { <input type="hidden" name="lt" value="10"> } {% else document.getElementById('spa-price').checked = true %} { <input type="hidden" name="lt" value="{{ price.getLt }}"> } {%endif%}